# Why can my <tr>s only be dragged (connectToSortable) to other tables only once?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using draggable with connectToSortable to allow `<tr>`s from my tables to be dragged and added to other tables.

It works great, but once I drag a `<tr>` to another table, it cannot be moved again, except for within its own (new) table. Is this an inherent limitation of jQuery UI or did I do something wrong?

Sortable:

```
$("#sem1").sortable({
        receive: function (event, ui) { 
            ui.item.remove();} 
    });

$("#sem2").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) { 
        ui.item.remove();}
    });
```

Draggable:

```
$("#sem1 tr").draggable({ connectToSortable: "#sem1, #sem2",helper:"clone"});
$("#sem2 tr").draggable({ connectToSortable: "#sem1, #sem2",helper:"clone"});
```

I had to use the clone helper and then remove because otherwise the drag would do funky things like overlap rows... open to any suggestions!

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.s, this is a follow-up to a question I had previously gotten answered:

[Are dynamically created table rows not targetable by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771000/are-dynamically-created-table-rows-not-targetable-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Got it - I just added the exact same code above to be executed on a onmouseup handler attached to my `<tr>`s